# Ember.js: passing null in hbs to a component

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

When you pass "null" as a property value in handlebars like that:

```
{{my-example myProperty=null}}
```

then in the component, the value of `myProperty` is not `null` as expected but `undefined`.

So first I thought it can always interpret all the unquoted strings as the (let's say) controller properties. But if you write:

```
{{my-example myProperty=true}}
```

it is interpreted as the boolean value = true.

Shouldn't it be that at first, ember checks all the reserved words and then tries to find the properties of that name? Maybe I'm missing something.

The other thing is if the concept of passing `null` to a component is correct... but I just wanted to know whether I should post an issue.

The code:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8dtugkdh/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother setting a components property to null from outside of itself. It's pretty common in some of the Ember components I've built to set properties to null within the component. Either on init or as a default value. Then, null check the values in your component's code during its lifespan.

A value that can or does become null can be passed into your component. At that point, the code that was checking for null should be fine as long as it was a truthy check.

Comment: I agree with all those statements. However, I'm curious why are they treating `null` as the name of the property and not `null` itself. My question is: "is it intentional"? Not "is it nice to pass `null` into your component"? I'm interested where is this inconsistency coming from.